# Each loop Haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have this `each` loop: (haml)

```
- @deals.each do |a|
     .slide
        %a{:href => "#"}
         - a.attachments.each do |a|
           = image_tag(a.file.url, :height =>"325px", :width =>"650px" )
            .caption{:style => "bottom:0"} 
              = a.description
```

Because `@deals` is combined query of 3 tables (models) I use `polymorphic_path` to generate the links of the images.

```
- @deals.each do |a|
     .slide
        %a{:href => "#"}
         - a.attachments.each do |a|
           = image_tag(a.file.url, :height =>"325px", :width =>"650px" ), polymorphic_path(@region, @city, a)
            .caption{:style => "bottom:0"} 
              = a.description
```

But this generates `region_city_attachment_path` which is not correct. The first each loop `a` variable store the correct value, but how can I `reach` the first `a` variable in the second `each` loop?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just give it another name.

```
- @deals.each do |a|
     .slide
        %a{:href => "#"}
         - a.attachments.each do |b|
           = image_tag(a.file.url, :height =>"325px", :width =>"650px" ), polymorphic_path(@region, @city, b)
            .caption{:style => "bottom:0"} 
              = a.description
```

Answer (score 14):

you should be more clear when using variable names, do something like

```
- @deals.each do |deal|
  .slide
    %a{:href => "#"}
      - deal.attachments.each do |attachment|
        ..
```

it's a really bad practice to use names such as "a"/"b"/"x" when you can write a much more readable code

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use the same name for both of them, and everything will turn out fine.